# Условия табличного объединения laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Laravel 9. Не получается задать условие табличного объединения на поле типа date.
Мой код:

```
$result['rooms'] = Room::select('rooms.real_num')
    ->leftJoin('bookings', function ($join) {
        $join->on('rooms.id', '=', 'bookings.room_id')
            ->where('bookings.date_start', '>=', strtotime($data['start']));
    })
    ->get();
```

Свежих решений не нашёл, в официальной документации не описано условие именно на столбцы с датой

Comment: А что именно не получается? Ошибку получаете? Или что?

Comment: стоит catch на \Illuminate\Database\QueryException. В этом случае он не срабатывает. Код попросту выплёвывает в консоль 500 ошибку. Думаю, ошибка в синтаксисе

Comment: "Код попросту выплёвывает в консоль 500 ошибку. Думаю, ошибка в синтаксисе" - а в логах что пишет?

Comment: Лог пишет local.ERROR: Undefined variable $data {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable $data at \\app\\Http\\Controllers\\BookingController.php:45). Попробовал вернуть $data['start'] в этом месте - получилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как будто у вас проблема не с датой, а с областью видимости. Переменную $data нужно передать в функцию.

```
$result['rooms'] = Room::select('rooms.real_num')
    ->leftJoin('bookings', function ($join) use($data) {
        $join->on('rooms.id', '=', 'bookings.room_id')
            ->where('bookings.date_start', '>=', strtotime($data['start']));
    })
    ->get();
```